# Is a new ESTA needed for my next US connecting flight?

Tags: esta

I applied for an ESTA because of my recent US flight to San Francisco. For my next flight, though, I will stop in the US because that's where my connecting flight will depart.

When I applied for an ESTA, I was requested to specify whether that was a connecting flight or not; it wasn't in that case. This time, it is. Do I have to apply for a new ESTA, so I can specify this is a connecting flight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you should not have to re-apply.

From the [Customs and Border Control](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1126/~/esta---length-of-approval) Website:

> Your ESTA authorization is generally valid for multiple trips over a
>   period of two years (starting the date that you are approved) or until
>   your passport expires, whichever comes first*. This means that as long
>   as you received an ESTA authorization to travel, you do not have to
>   reapply during the validity period.

If you are concerned, and assuming you will exit immigration and stay in the US before boarding your connecting flight, you can retrieve your application to check it's validity and update your US address if necessary [here](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/).